# Tooltip for checkbox list items using Knockout.Js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, tooltip, checkboxlist, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I want to add tooltips to each item in a checkbox list using KO.JS.
I have gone through some of the examples online and implemented with the help of the sample given here :

http://jsfiddle.net/pardahlman/6J7wE/12/

I have written a handler as below:

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).tooltip({
                title: valueUnwrapped
            });
        },
    };
```

Code in HTML :

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: user">
<li>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: val, checked: $root.chosenUsers">
<label data-bind="text: name, attr: { 'for': name } , tooltip : name"></label>
</li>
</ul>
```

But the tooltip doesnt show up. Not sure where I am going wrong.
I tried implementing the bootstrap tooltip. I got the sample code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/shail/vSTLU/2/

Below is the html code:

```
  <label id="contextBox" data-bind="text: name, attr: { 'for': name }" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Tooltip on top"></label>
```

Below is the code in JS file:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
       $('contextBox').tooltip();
});
```

Unfortunately, none of the above implementations worked.
Please suggest where I am going wrong.
If there is any other better method to do this, please do suggest.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your selector is wrong. You have to use id selector $("#contentBox").tooltip();

Comment: Thanks Kavitha, I have corrected that line of code. Still, doesnt work.

Comment: Can u create new jsfiddle with ur code and provide the link?

Comment: First jsfiddle has a popup for me in, even looks nice if I [fix the css url](http://jsfiddle.net/6J7wE/45/).

Comment: Hi Kavitha, This is the fiddle, I have created it http://jsfiddle.net/3jbdgscf/

Comment: As Jeroen suggested, I am not sure if this is a CSS issue. I have added my code to the fiddle. I am unable to figure out the exact problem, its simple thing but doesnt work. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Check your External Resources on your fiddle.  None of them are valid -- they're all 404's.  This means you're not getting any of the bootstrap files nor knockout loaded.

Comment: Thank You Patrick. While creating a fiddle, I didnt add the references properly. But in my html file, I do have proper references but it didnt work. Now, I have corrected the extrenal references and updated the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3jbdgscf/1/ and still this doesnt seem to work. May be am still missing something not sure.

Comment: Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3jbdgscf/5/. There were few binding issues like input checkbox doesnt support text attr.